# Can both Javascript AND Java code be included in a WAR overlay?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

We'll probably start using WAR overlays soon.  We have some Javascript and JSF 2 custom Facelets components that belong together, along with some managed-bean Java classes.  Is it possible to bundle everything, including the Java classes, in a Maven WAR overlay?  Would it be best to put the Java code in a different Maven module for some reason?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the JavaScript? Is this [server-side](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html) code? Is it a client-side [web resource](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WCC3.html)? Is it a JSF [resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to put the Java code in a jar and other resources (js, css, images etc...) in a war.